# onPageFinished sometimes not called Android WebView

Tags: android, printing, webview

I'm using a webview to show the printing preview, the problem is that sometimes the webview is not shown. When that happens, the onPageFinished() callback is not called. What I find strange is that It works most of the times but sometimes it doesn't.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);

    webView.loadData(html,
            "text/html", "UTF-8");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view,url);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished: ");

            PrintDocumentAdapter printDocumentAdapter = new PrintDocumentAdapterWrapper(view.createPrintDocumentAdapter());
            printManager = (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
            printManager.print(webViewName, printDocumentAdapter, printAttributes);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);` instead of `webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");`.
From what I read the two methods have a completly different implementation